# cannot get regex group capture in "either or" case

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I got something that works for one match but not two. I have to find any text such as "account" or "customer" in a file header. It could be one, both, or none. I have headers of a .csv (tab separated) like this:

```
test_header = apple   orange  account  customer
```

then I do

```
match = re.match(".*(account)|(customer).*", test_header, re.IGNORECASE)
```

The match is finding match.group(1) as "account", but I when I print match.group(2), it returns "None".

What am I missing? I've looked at other similar examples here but not finding what's wrong.

Comment: I think you might want `re.findall`?

Comment: Regex is not the tool you want for the job you describe. All you need is `'account' in test_header` and `'customer' in test_header` to see if those values are present or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use re.findall():

```
import re


test_header = 'apple   orange  account  customer'
match = re.findall(r"account|customer", test_header, re.IGNORECASE)

print(match)
```

Output:

```
['account', 'customer']
```

Comment: You need to add word boundaries to the regex so that it does match, for example, "accounting".